# Creation parameters menu greyed out

Tags: cycles-render-engine

When adding a UV Sphere mesh in Blender 2.8, the creation parameters menu on the bottom left of the attached image for this UV Sphere seems to be greyed out. Any idea why this might be? Thanks.

[image: et]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be an option in the preferences (menu 'edit' and 'preferences').

Check global undo:

[image]