# Mesh "Add" menu is not working 2.8

Tags: modeling, mesh, subdivision-surface, operator, pie-menu

I'm new with blender. I'm currently watching some tutorials but I'm having a hard time figuring how to fix this sub-menu when adding mesh (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> ) I can't change any values and suddenly disappear. I tried to show that option but still doesn't work for me.

[image]

Comment: is it possible to have access to your .blend file?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148611/creation-parameters-menu-greyed-out

Comment: Problem solved Thank you!