# Creation parameters menu is greyed out

Tags: mesh

I have the exact same issue as in [Creation parameters menu greyed out](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148611/creation-parameters-menu-greyed-out) , when I add an object all the parameters in the Add  box are greyed out, however the solution in this previous answer does not resolve it (the Global Undo was already checked, I tried unchecking it and checking it again and it did not resolve it). Is there anything else that could cause this?